# Elfinder Rails and Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elfinder

I am using Elfinder Rails for Media Manger in my application. I am working on to store the media files to Amazon S3 storage. I try to use the gem el_finder_s3. I created bucket and provided all the configurations like.

```
  def elfinder
    ElFinderS3::Connector.new(
      :mime_handler => ElFinderS3::MimeType,
      :root => '/',
      :url => 's3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
      :thumbs => true,
      :thumbs_size => 100,
      :thumbs_directory => 'thumbs',
      :home => t('admin.media.home'),
      :original_filename_method => lambda { |file| "#{File.basename(file.original_filename, File.extname(file.original_filename)).parameterize}#{File.extname(file.original_filename)}" },
      :default_perms => {:read => true, :write => true, :rm => true, :hidden => false},
      :server => {
        :bucket_name => 'bucket_name',
        :region => 'ap-southeast-1',
        :access_key_id => 'acces_key',
        :secret_access_key => 'secret_key',
        :cdn_base_path => 's3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
      }
    ).run(params)
  end
```

Rails application is connect with S3 but elfinder doesn't show the file contents. I checked the bucket, thumb folder was created but elfinder was unable to load the contents. 
[image: screen shot]

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed with the update of the above script. Here is the updated script.

```
def elfinder
    h, r = ElFinderS3::Connector.new(
      :mime_handler => ElFinderS3::MimeType,
      :root => '/',
      :url => 's3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
      :thumbs => true,
      :thumbs_size => 100,
      :thumbs_directory => 'thumbs',
      :home => t('admin.media.home'),
      :original_filename_method => lambda { |file| "#{File.basename(file.original_filename, File.extname(file.original_filename)).parameterize}#{File.extname(file.original_filename)}" },
      :default_perms => {:read => true, :write => true, :rm => true, :hidden => false},
      :server => {
        :bucket_name => 'bucket_name',
        :region => 'ap-southeast-1',
        :access_key_id => 'acces_key',
        :secret_access_key => 'secret_key',
        :cdn_base_path => 's3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
      }
    ).run(params)
headers.merge!(h)

if r.empty?
  (render :nothing => true) and return
end

render :json => r, :layout => false
end
```